# Can magic lamp effect be enabled on Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME?

Tags: 18.04, compiz, gnome-shell, minimize

Is there a way to enable *magic lamp effect* (or genie effect) which is on Mac OS in Ubuntu **GNOME** environment? It looks like *Compiz* isn't working on GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3740/compiz-alike-magic-lamp-effect

Here you can see the extension in action: https://youtu.be/DKicPyYI04w

Answer (score 0):

It could be a gnome extension but nobody create it https://extensions.gnome.org/
So you can't have this effect for now.

Comment: What about nowadays?